# How to change database password in wp-config.php in multiple Wordpress installations

Tags: wordpress

I have 50+ Wordpress installations in /home/user/domains/. Each domain has it's own public_html and all have the same database password in wp-config.php so I must change this word in all wp-config.php files. I am moving to a new server and I want to change this old password.

Path example: /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-config.php

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with a quick find and replace based on your operating system. If you tell me your operating system, I can probably help you more.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20, ssh only access. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I think this is better suited for the unix/ssh category, since it's a replacement in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/old_password/new_password/g' wp-config.php
```

***Before run this command, Make sure you use the `old_password` only for the database in the wp-config file.***

Comment: Thanks! Can I use it like this: sed -i 's/old_password/new_password/g'"/home/user/domains/*/public_html/wp-config.php"